# Microsoft Word - Citation button greyed-out

Tags: citations, microsoft-word

I am doing a Practical Assessment Task for high school, and we have to use citations. I have a problem however, after page four, I am unable to use citations. The button is greyed-out. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Questions about Microsoft Word [are indeed on-topic here](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1102/23927), but you may have better luck on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), where they're also on-topic. (Admittedly, their name doesn't really make that obvious.) Cross-posting the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites is discouraged, but if you don't receive an answer here within a couple of days, then Super User would be my recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Writing!

I had to do some software sleuthing, and according to [this forum post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2010/insert-citation-greyed-out/12c03065-5b82-48a5-bad7-cb7262daa13a), this problem can happen when you have Microsoft Word version conflicts, i.e. if you ported a new document to an older version of Microsoft Word or vice versa. The citation feature was only added in newer versions of Word.

In order to fix the problem, the poster suggests:

> ...saving to Word 97–2003 (*.doc) format and then back to *.docx seems to fix the problem. You will have to recreate the Bibliography field, because the *.doc format doesn't support it.

If you have a lot of citations and don't want to recreate the Bibliography section, another commenter on that post suggests:

> You can collapse the size of the 'bibliography tagged' content back to where it needs to be. This is akin to removing content from inside a bookmark to 'collapse' the bookmark. If you cut the content from the start to immediately in front of the bibliography and paste it to to the end then that section now behaves. You can do the same for the chunk 'inside the tagged area' that follows the bibliography. Finally, you can clean up the returns around the bibliography itself and then cut that chunk out and place it where it needs to go.

Comment: I am sorry but I have the same problem and that is just unacceptable. I have over 100 citations. Recreating is just not practical.

Comment: @HeatherDawn I edited to add the text of another comment on that post which suggests an alternate idea, if that would help.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to delete citations from the list as the "-" was greyed out but I found that by deleting all instances of a particular citation in the text the "-" became available and I was able to delete the citation from the list.